# How to insert value only if the input is blank or not identical

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having a simple problem that I know most of you already solved.

I am working on `Inventory System` and I need to log the users for each machine they were assigned to.

So I have 2 database table, One for the `Asset Inventory`and `Asset Logs`.
I can successfully add a log to the database but whenever I update the the `Asset Inventory`, like putting comments to it. It will also insert a log to `Asset Logs` that will duplicate the entry.

I've already tried using if statements like `!empty` and `!=` at the same time.
I also tried using if else but I don't think that would fix it.

right now I have `if (!empty($assignedHeadset) || $assignedHeadset != $hserial) {`
I tested to query the headset serial from the database and match it to the new or existing serial in the select field. but it doesn't work

I use !empty only to insert if the field is fresh.

I tried to remove the `|| $assignedHeadset != $hserial)` but that will keep insert a log whenever I add a serial or update the comments of the serial.

This is where I check the existing `Headset Serial` from the database.

```
//Check Headset ID
$sql_headset_id = "SELECT id, serial_number FROM asset_inventory WHERE serial_number='$assignedHeadset'";
$result = $conn->query($sql_headset_id);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $headset_id = $row['id'];
        $hserial = $row['serial_number'];
    }
}
```

And this is where the `$assignedHeadset` coming from. It's from the `Select Field`.

```
$assignedHeadset = $_POST['assignedHeadset'];
```

And this is the code that I am having issues on inserting the asset logs.

```
if (!empty($assignedHeadset) || $assignedHeadset != $hserial) {
    //asset logs
    $sql_log = "INSERT INTO asset_logs (username, inventory_id, claim_status, processed_by, date_processed) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    $stmt_log = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt_log, $sql_log)) {
        die ("LOG QUERY FAILED" . mysqli_error($conn));
    }
}
```

I expect only to insert a log if the field is empty or the serial is changed.

Thank you in advance I hope you can help me.

Comment: _"whenever I update the the data"_  with an `INSERT` statement? I would use [`UPDATE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) personally

Comment: share the code where you are creating $assignedHeadset or $hserial

Comment: I have 2 data. One for the Serial number data which includes, other inputs. That has an update code. I have create a separate code only for INSERT logs which I am having a problem. I will update my description. @Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add column `serial_number` to your assert_logs table and add qnique index on `serial_number`.

Then use insert on duplicate update instead of insert.

`"INSERT INTO asset_logs (username, inventory_id, claim_status, processed_by, date_processed,serial_number) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,serial_number) on duplicate key update set date_processed = now()"`

Comment: Hi @Kris Roofe, I am getting an error message.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET date_processed = now()' at line 1

Comment: @jackflick it's just a demo in my answer you have to adjust to your case.

Comment: It's working now Kris. I removed the "SET". Thanks for the help :)